# Mac OSX - screenshot tool broken after settings change

Tags: macos, mac

There appears to be no good answer for this after several minutes searching: After creating a new user on the Mac, new user changed default screen shot settings (un-checked "save to file", leaving "copy to clipboard" selected for both full screen and partial screen options).

The tool completely broke - the command keys CMD+Shift+3 and CMD+Shift+4 no longer work. There is no screen shot tool cursor, no camera noise, and nothing copied.

Restoring the defaults and re-booting did not help. Repairing disk permissions also did not help.

Does anyone have a fix? The user literally uses this tool several times a minute - "grab" is too clunky to be a good alternative.

Comment: So what happens when they use the shortcuts?  Nothing at all?  What's in the clipboard at that point?

Comment: nothing at all. No sound, no screenshot cursor - as if it never existed.

Answer (score 0):

Found it. Hope this will help someone else. I don't know how it happened, but the keyboard shortcuts spontaneously changed. In settings - keyboard - shortcuts tab - screen shots (on the left), double clicked on the shortcut and put it back to what it was supposed to be.